# Ruby On Rails: jQuery datepicker only works when refresh page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, rubygems, turbolinks

The problem I am having is that when I navigate through the form page and I click on the date_sent on my text field, jQuery is supposed to pop-up a datepicker. However, I get nothing at first, but when I refresh the page it works.

I am almost sure that my problem is with turbolinks, because I assume that my JavaScript does not get loaded because of turbolinks. However, I do not want to remove turbolinks because my page renders slow without it. How can I make this work?

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require cocoon
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**application.scss**

```
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 *= require_tree .
 */

@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'sites';
```

**form.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
    $('#send_date').datepicker()
```

**form.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group" >
      <%= f.label :date_sent, class: 'control-label' %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :date_sent, id: 'send_date' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try `turbolinks:load` event ?

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
```

instead:

```
$(document).ready, ->
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? I am not using "$(document).ready, ->" anywhere.

Comment: Try use `$(document).on "turbolinks:load", -> `  as first line in your `coffe` file